# Test for null parameter in .properties file for MessageFormat

Tags: java, resourcebundle, messageformat

Is it possible, with resource bundles and MessageFormat to have the following result?

- when I call `getBundle("message.07", "test")` to get `"Group test"`
- when I call `getBundle("message.07",  null)` to get `"No group selected"`

Every example I found on the Internet is with planets, with files on the disk and so on.

I only need to check if one parameter is `null` (*or doesn't exist*) in the resource bundle's properties file. I hope to find a special format for the null parameter something like `{0,choice,null#No group selected|notnull#Group {0}}`.

The method I use to get the bundles is:

```
public String getBundle(String key, Object... params) {
  try {
    String message = resourceBundle.getString(key);
    if (params.length == 0) {
      return message;
    } else {
      return MessageFormat.format(message, params);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return "???";
  }
}
```

I also call this method for other bundles, like

- `getBundle("message.08", 1, 2)` => `"Page 1 of 2"` (always parameters, no need to check for `null`)
- `getBundle("message.09")` => `"Open file"` (no parameters, no need to check for `null`)

What should I write in my .properties file for `message.07` to have the result described?
What I have now is:

```
message.07=Group {0} 
message.08=Page {0} of {1}    # message with parameters where I always send them
message.09=Open file          # message without parameters
```

Comment: It seems that the answer to my question is that there's no special format for a `String` passed to `MessageFormat` to  check if a parameter is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.properties` file,

```
message.07=Group {0} 
message.08=Page {0} of {1}
message.09=Open file
message.null = No group selected
```

And then you need to change your code to put an explicit check `params` for `null`. And if `null` then you can do something like `resourceBundle.getString(NULL_MSG)`. Where `NULL_MSG` will be this,

```
private static final String NULL_MSG = "message.null";
```

So, now your original method would become something like this.

```
public String getBundle(String key, Object... params) {
  String message = null;
  try {
    if (params == null) {
      message = resourceBundle.getString(NULL_MSG);
    } else {
      message = MessageFormat.format(resourceBundle.getString(key), params);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return message;
}
```

Calling my method like below,

```
getBundle("message.07", "test") // returning 'Group test'
getBundle("message.07", null) // returning 'No group selected'
getBundle("message.08", 1, 2) // returning 'Page 1 of 2'
getBundle("message.08", null) // returning 'No group selected'
getBundle("message.09", new Object[0]) // returning 'Open file'
getBundle("message.09", null) // returning 'No group selected'
```

Now tell me where is the problem?

Comment: I would like not to change that method, because it is used everywhere in my code and it should work with the rest of the messages (where the parameters are numbers, strings...) where I don't need to check for `null`. Also it is possible to have more cases like this (more messages with null testing)

Comment: It wouldn't break the code anywhere, just change the internal behaviour. The parameters are not changed, neither the return type. I don't see any problem.

Comment: You don't need the supplementary key for each and every message. Just make a generic for `null`. That will suffice, AFAICS. Moreover, check my edits.

Comment: I added more details to my question. For example, with your changes, the call `getBundle("message.09")` would not give the expected result.

Comment: Do you have an overloaded method which just take one argument? Moreover, in this case, my method will give you the result, "Open file". What else you are expecting?

Comment: I don't have an overloaded method with one argument, because: the `getBundle` method has varargs, and when `params` is a zero-length array, I will  have something exactly like a method with one argument. That's why I check it with `if (params.length == 0) {`.

Comment: You must understand that calling  MessageFormat.format(message, params) with null param, or zero length param, will not do anything to your message. It will just return you the message as it is. And thats what you are doing after checking for length.

Comment: @Oscar, I don't understand what is your comment got to do with my question.

Comment: @True Soft: Sorry about that. Never mind.. erh.. wrong number :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend not trying to change the bundle functionality (even if you have a getBundle method encapsulating it).

Simply do in your code:

```
getBundle(param == null? "message.07.null": "message.07", param)
```

Or make another method:

```
getBundleOrNull("message.07", param, "message.07.null")
```

that does

```
public String getBundleOrNull(String key, value, nullKey) {
   return getBundle(value == null? nullKey: key: value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will choose to make something that is a combination of your answer and Vinegear's, and it's hard to select an accepted answer. I'll vote your answer, anyway.